# IE 11 just works when Dev mode is active

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I'm investigating a situation on my web application but I'm in trouble to figurate what is going on.

The application is a ReactJs. That has been working very well in all supported browser. Recently I was doing some tests when I realized one simple functionality wasn't work as expected just in IE 11. When I turned on the Development tools this functionality works.

Basically, the is after a success ajax call my application must be reset some values on state and return to initial state. I would like to understand what is the difference on IE11 when it has the development tool on. Another thing I would like to know is how can I debug it better than add multiple alerts to try to understand what is going on.

Comment: Are you using console.log()?

Comment: @PhilipTinney, I can use it, but it will not display without Develop toll opened

Comment: I was just curious, since in IE using console.log() will cause the javascript to fail, unless developer tools are open.

Comment: is console.log() cause javascript fails if developer tool is off?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML has the following at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

These force IE to use the latest HTML5 features.

When in developer mode, you can control which rendering engine to emulate. Chances are that you have the "Emulation" set to something a little more toward "edge" (which is what the META forces).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is almost always an IE performance issue.  Ajax calls are asynchronous, so I would check if your ajax call has returned by the time your code reaches the function that fails. If you are using the Ajax data in the function that's failing, double check the data and make sure it exists at the point of failure.

Comment: The post or the return will not change depending on dev tools is on or off. I didn't understand your point.